# How to redirect to main page is no pattern is satisfied in django?

Tags: python, django

If url not exists, how to redirect to main page?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='main'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^app/$',views.app,name='app'),
)
```

Let's say someone type `http://localhost:9000/something/login/aaaa/` page `aaaa` not exists. How can redirect to main page from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a pattern that match any url at the end of the url patterns:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='main'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^app/$',views.app, name='app'),
    url(r'^.*$', redirect('/')), # <------------
)
```

Comment: Thanks!... I hate regexp :)